# how do I write a code that´s applying letters to numbers and prints names into a sum of numbers?

Tags: numbers, names

For example A = 1 , Z = 26 , Aron = 48

Non English-letter character like space or apostrophe can be ignored
Lowercase and uppercase letters are equal

I am new to programming and try some practices with java in order to learn from this.

Comment: A lookup table, vlookup() or index() with match() will go either way.